# Use of negative binomial regression for clustered and pseudo-count data

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, negative-binomial-distribution

I am trying to test whether sleep improves over the course of a treatment intervention.

Through surveys sent periodically across 6 months, people self-report how many days per week they had difficulty falling asleep and how many days they had difficulty staying asleep, which are then added together to give a range of values from 0-14. My base model takes this form:

```
days_impacted ~ time + (1|participant)
```

If I look at the whole distribution of  `days_impacted` across all time and people, it fits a zero-inflated negative binomial distribution. But there are caveats:

- `days_impacted`  are clustered at the participant-level (i.e., `(1|participant)`), and for any given person, their responses probably don't fit a zero-inflated negative binomial distribution.
- The shape of the `days_impacted` distribution likely changes across time. For example, it may be less zero-inflated to begin with if most people have some trouble sleeping, but become more zero-inflated if the intervention works.
- `days_impacted`  proxies for counted days, but are not true counts.

What's the best approach to use here? Can this data be fit with a negative binomial distribution, despite the caveats?

Comment: Try using `glmer.nb`. Use rootograms to make visual assessment of count models.